# Can Anyone Help With This OpenGL Error?

Tags: games, steam, opengl

Well After the headache of running Microsoft's Windows for a month, to play some games a fried recommended. I am in a blissful state now that I have returned to Linux :D. Just when I thought it couldn't get any better, it did! Well as a matter of speaking. Arma 3 was magically in my Steam OS + Linux games, maybe they haven't updated any info...Or sent out the news, as I could not find any explanation for why this Windows only game Installed on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. With excitement and joy i was put down hard to find an issue with OpenGL :'(. It says I need OGL 4.1 to run the game. I added some screenshots, and I cannot find any information as to how I need to go about obtaining OGL 4.1. So hopefully you guys can help me out, as you have before. If you need anything else be sure to let me know! Well i'm off to do some research on this myself, and answer some Ask Ubuntu questions if possible XD!

[image: Arma 3(1)][image: Arma 3(2)][image: Arma 3(3)]